# Toggle invisible and visible of LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, xml

I currently have code that should make the LinearLayout toggle between being VISIBLE and GONE, but it only toggles if it is visible, and does not toggle if the Layout is Gone. Could someone explain what i have done wrong?

XML:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/info_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/myimage"
    android:onClick="toggleInfo"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id = "@+id/text_box"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/test"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:background="@color/white"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
public void toggleInfo(View view) {
    LinearLayout infoText = findViewById(R.id.text_box);

    if (infoText.getVisibility() == LinearLayout.GONE) {
        infoText.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (infoText.getVisibility() == LinearLayout.VISIBLE) {
        infoText.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: it should be `if().. else` or `if()...else if()` and not `if ... if` which you are using.

Comment: so change your code to `if(test){ set visible } else{ set hidden }`

Comment: `infoText.setVisibility(infoText.getVisibility() == LinearLayout.GONE ? LinearLayout.VISIBLE : LinearLayout.GONE);`

Answer (score 1):

By default your layout is visible. And when you are calling the method, it checks if the view is visible. The second if condition satisfies with it. So first time the LinearLayout.GONE is getting called.

But when you are clicking second time (now your view is not visible), the first condition satisfies and LinearLayout.VISIBLE is getting called. Now your view is visible. So the second condition also satisfies, and the LinearLayout.GONE is getting called again.

Just put and else and it will work.

```
public void toggleInfo(View view) {
    LinearLayout infoText = findViewById(R.id.text_box);

    if (infoText.getVisibility() == LinearLayout.GONE) {
        infoText.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
    }else if (infoText.getVisibility() == LinearLayout.VISIBLE) {
        infoText.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
public void toggleInfo(View view) {
    LinearLayout infoText = findViewById(R.id.text_box);
    infoText.setVisibility(infoText.getVisibility() == LinearLayout.GONE ? LinearLayout.VISIBLE : LinearLayout.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rupam absolutely right. Another way to fix is - to add return to your first condition
also avoid using `LinearLayout.GONE`
better use `View.GONE` instead(if something will change - for example you will decide to use RelativeLayout instead of current LinearLayout... well... you got me I think)

```
if (infoText.getVisibility() == LinearLayout.GONE) {
        infoText.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
        return;
    }

    if (infoText.getVisibility() == LinearLayout.VISIBLE) {
        infoText.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
    }
```